# Execute the query on getValueAt and return the results asynchronously

Tags: java, swing, asynchronous, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am implementing a swing jtable with a huge number of data, i want the data to be loaded at the moment of getValueAt in the data model and print "Loading" in the cell and return the data later, I dont wanna to execute the query in the UI Thread. Any ideas to de that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I am implementing a swing jtable with a huge number of data, i want
>   the data to be loaded at the moment of getValueAt in the data model
>   and print "Loading" in the cell and return the data later, I dont
>   wanna to execute the query in the UI Thread. Any ideas to de that?
>   Thanks

use Workers Thread

- `Runnable#Thread`, output to XxxTableModel must be wrapped into invokeLater
- `SwingWorker`, output from methods `publish`(synchronous), `process`(synchronous), `done`(asynchronous) is done on EDT

Comment: [SwingWorker & JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[swing]+[jtable]+swingworker), with the same logics for quite easier `Runnable#Thread`